# How to declare and init nested enum with reserved keyword as type name in Swift?

Tags: swift, enums, reserved-words

I'm having a hard time to figure out how to declare a certain nested `enum` and calling one of it's automatic constructors. This `enum` i'm trying to declare is supposed to have a reserved keyword as type name.

Here is a simplified example of what i'm trying to do:

```
import Foundation

public class Foo {}

public extension Foo {
    enum `Type`: Int {
        case bar
    }
}

var type: Foo.`Type`
type = Foo.`Type`(rawValue: 0)
```

This doesn't compile in Swift 5.2 with error

> error: type 'Foo.Type' has no member 'init'

I'm pretty sure it is just a matter of getting the syntax right but i just can't figure it out. Anyone can please explain how to do it or is it just impossible all together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this specific thing you want to do. That's why nobody uses nested types named `Type`, even though we all want to—the language already provides this type, and you don't get to override it with your own. We all use the Objective-C style naming of just smashing the word Type right up there without a proper delimiter.

`FooType` is what you've got to work with.

Comment: That is a very interesting hint! I didn't realize that my declaration is in fact an override of Swift's `Type` declaration.

Comment: @mbi I go around this naming it Kind